# Black Screen when trying to refresh view controller

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm working on a word search puzzle game for the iphone and I'm trying to implement a restart button for the app. The restart button should be able to initialize a new view controller, generate a new puzzle, and display the new puzzle.

As of now, in the puzzle game view, I have a button that on-click it opens the pause menu view using a modal segue.(The pause menu have three buttons, resume, restart, main menu.) I then made the puzzle game controller a delegate of the pause menu, that receives the notification when the buttons are pressed. The resume and main menu button works, but I'm having trouble reloading the view with the restart button. The puzzle is inside a container view, that has a collection controller that creates the grid and displays the letter.

With the current code I have, when I click the restart button, all i see a black screen that only shows the navigation bar. But once I click the pause menu button(located in nav bar) and then click the resume button in the pause menu, i see the view with the new generated puzzle.

Below is the code in the pauseMenuController:

```
- (IBAction)IBARestart:(id)sender {
         [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
         [self.delegate goToRestart];
      }
```

Now here is the code in my puzzleGameController:

```
  -(void)goToRestart{        
     self.view = nil;
     [self.view.window setNeedsDisplay];

    PuzzleCollectionControllerViewController *puzzleInstance = [self.childViewControllers lastObject]; 
        puzzleInstance.view = nil; 
        [puzzleInstance.view setNeedsDisplay]; // I tried reloading the cointainer view too, but it still shows black screen


    }
```

Anyone have any idea why is it showing a black screen? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Instead of nil out a view controller's main view,  try nil out the VC itself.  And then restart it with a new instance.  Show your snippets for your pause and resume button would help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is enough code, to get your problem..

But my concerns on this are:
Why do you "nil" self.view on restart? If you do this, the view is "nil" and therefore won't display anything, same for puzzleInstance.view.

You could nil / free the memory for this on viewDidUnload, as the view will get set again on viewDidLoad, but normally I just "nil" / "dealloc" any properties, outlets etc. (on viewDidUnload or dealloc, depending on where I set / re-set them) and not the view itself.
"setNeedsDisplay" will just "redraw" the view, but if it's nil, I'm afraid there is nothing to redraw. So I'm pretty sure that's your problem here.

What is different, or what is happening when you press "resume" (code?).

Comment: I tried to dealloc memory using ViewDidUnload, but that method is deprecated for ios 6. The reason that I originally did "nil" on self.view is because I wanted to force, ViewDidLoad to run again. Most of my logic is in the viewDidLoad, but the only thing i have there is a timer that i have for the puzzle. As for when i press resume, the only thing i have in there is a method that resumes the timer i have for the puzzle.

Comment: You only need dealloc if you are not using ARC. You cannot be sure when viewDid(Un)load gets called, except when the view gets on screen the first time. Ios may unload the view in low memory situations (when its not on screen) and load it again when the view gets back on screen. But you can use viewWillAppear which will get called each time before the view will appear. So just create a method "updateUI" which you call in both viewDidLoad ans viewWillAppear. Hope this will help you :-)

Comment: Yeah I tried to that and it still didn't work. I needed to implement a category view to choose puzzle themed words, so my workaround was to use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true] in the goToRestart Method. Thanks for your help anyways!